# Curl or wget to download file with login required OS X

Tags: curl, download, terminal, wget

My teacher have this website where he post slides and exercises for his classes, the fact is, there are more then a hundred files and I am looking for a faster and easier way to download all at once, this is the website: http://aprender.ead.unb.br/course/view.php?id=3232 it is login required though.
This page have links to a bunch of pdf's like: http://aprender.ead.unb.br/pluginfile.php/215601/mod_resource/content/1/T1.pdf, I realised that the pdfs directories change only in the T1 part. So I tried downloading in this way:

```
curl --user USERNAME:PASSWORD  -L -k -O 'http://aprender.ead.unb.br/pluginfile.php/215602/mod_resource/content/1/T{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}.pdf'
```

I've been reading some topics but I can't figure out what is not working, the file does appear in my finder but when I try to open it:

```
"The file “T2.pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the files are corrupt because they contain the HTTP headers. You can inspect them in a text editor to see if this is correct by looking at the first few lines.

'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf' should trigger the file to download directly.

```
curl --user USERNAME:PASSWORD -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf' -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' -L -k -O 'http://aprender.ead.unb.br/pluginfile.php/215602/mod_resource/content/1/T[1-13].pdf'
```

However depending on the type of authentication the site uses you may need to store a cookie and have curl use the cookie.

Comment: I have tried using your solution but the files still download corrupted. I've tried merging your answer with @drew010 and still download corrupted. This is the code i did with the merging: `--cookie name=value -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf' -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' -L -k -O 'http://aprender.ead.unb.br/pluginfile.php/215601/mod_resource/content/1/T2.pdf'
`

Comment: what do the first few bytes of the downloaded file look like? Since you're on a Mac open it using textwrangler

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  dir="ltr" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Erro</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://aprender.ead.unb.br/theme/image.php/aprender1/theme/1443127684/favicon" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="moodle, Erro" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ `

Comment: So it definitely has html data; what if you change the extension from `.pdf` to `.html` and then open it in a web browser. Judging by the `<title>Erro</title>` it is probably an error message related to the login, instead of the PDF file that you expect.

Comment: Oh my god, I realize that the "215602" part changes too, so I have to write `'http://aprender.ead.unb.br/pluginfile.php/2156[01-13]/mod_resource/content/1/T[1-13].pdf'`

Comment: Is that anyway to make increment both at same time?

Answer (score 2):

This website uses application level authentication so curl's `--user` option will not work and give you the ability to download the PDFs.

I'd suggest logging in with your web browser and then using it's built in tools/options to view your cookies for that site and call cURL like this:

```
curl --coookie name1=value1 --cookie name2=value2 ... URLs
```

This will supply the login cookies you got from your browser so when cURL makes its request it will get through the login.